# Tensorflow unreused Variable Scope

Tags: tensorflow

I write codes like below, but I'm not sure whether these fully-connected layers share same variables or not.

```
with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
        _loss= tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, output_size), x_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

> whether these fully-connected layers share same variables or not?

[`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) op behaves similarly as python native `map` function. So here all the elements of the list are exposed to same parameter of the fully connected layer(share parameters).

Comment: Then if I need they have different parameters, what should I do?

Comment: first split the input and then apply different `fc` layers